# PHP interpreter behaving weird

Tags: php, class, output

I found this weird behaviour on classes. Is this a PHP Bug ?

```
<?php
class A
{

public function disp1()
{
echo "1";

}

public function disp3()
{
echo "3";
}

}

$a = new A;
echo $a->disp1()." 2 ".$a->disp3();
```

**Expected Result**

1 2 3

**Actual Result**

13 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are `echo`ing what is already `echo`'d. Those two methods are run before the echo is rendered. So the `echo`s in each method are run first, then the echo outside your class is run. The only thing it will render, however, is `2`.

To get your expected result you need to **return** the values from each method:

```
class A {
    public function disp1() {
        return "1";
    }
    public function disp3() {
        return "3";
    }
}

$a = new A;
echo $a->disp1()." 2 ".$a->disp3();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have echo in methods, not return. So first it will echo 1 then 3, then the result which is now " 2 " because the methods return NULL.